# Use TURN for remote port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding

I want to forward some ports on a machine behind a NAT to a publicly accessible server. I can do this via SSH (and doing so already successfully), however SSH encrypts all the traffic which in my case is not necessary and reduces throughput to ~25% of what is possible without encryption. Also, ssh feels like a very huge hammer for a small nail.

I was looking for alternative solutions, and read a bit about STUN and TURN. From what I gather at various websites it looks like TURN should be able to do this; however, I have not find anything in terms of a deeper explanation. So here are my questions:

a) is TURN actually a viable alternative?

b) how do I use TURN to establish port forwardings

Comment: Are you using SSH compression (-C)? What kind of application do you need to make available? What kind of NAT device do you have? Its firewall should be able to do the forwarding easily.

Comment: This is a generic TCP forwarder. The NAT device in question might vary, so I would like to not use NAT. As for ssh compression - the option to turn off compression has disappeared from ssh2 at some point in the past. I am using arcfour128 now.